# Problem after yesterday's update of linux libs 5.4.0-77

Tags: 20.04, updates, mdadm

I am experiencing a strange problem with the update that was shipped yesterday (linux libs 5.4.0-77). The machine is stuck in the update with:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-77-generic
```

It is reading very slowly all the disks as it seems, the process `mdadm` and later `grub-prob` ran over night, spending several hours of CPU. Any hints on what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the USB drives, disconnecting them made initramfs finish after reboot via

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`